# SSIS cannot convert text to date

Tags: ssis

I am trying to convert a text field in an XML file with a value of 2014-04-01T00:00:00-04:00 to a date via a data conversion component.

The full error message is 
**[Data Conversion [2]] Error: Data conversion failed while converting column "BKG_DATE" (417) to column "Converted_BKG_DATE" (26).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".**

The conversion is from a DT_WSTR to a database time [DT_DBTIME].

Please note I only need the date value from the xml field value.

Can anyone help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the Data Conversion component, try the Derived Column transformation, and derive the new column from an expression that builds the date by getting the appropriate substrings from the text column.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the date value, you need to convert to DT_DBDATE, which is a date structure that consists of year, month, and day. DT_DBTIME is a time structure that consists of hour, minute, and second, and so is unsuitable.

See MSDN > Integration Services Data Types: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms141036.aspx

To convert from date-time-with-offset values in this format 2014-04-01T00:00:00-04:00 to DT_DBDATE, you can use a Derived Column transformation with the following expression. In this example, the incoming values are in a column called RawDateTime.

```
(DT_DBDATE)LEFT(RawDateTime,10)
```

[image]

We can test it using a data viewer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the date came in this format:
2021-03-31T16:26:26Z

I found that the only date type that natively supported that format was DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET. This worked direct on my input file configuration -- I did not require a Derived Column transform.